# How to Align text with respect to image css

Tags: html, css

I want to align text to be with respect to image, the text is breaking and the rest of text is coming under image.

This is what i tried:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qtfj1bo0/1/)

HTML:

```
<section>
<div class="left"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/44/9f/02/449f02a1a0328ed5f311112b83407fdf.jpg" alt="" ></div>
<div class="right"><span>Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo </span></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
div.left{
  vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
}
div.right{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "text to be with respect to image"?

Comment: You want to `float: left` the image? https://jsfiddle.net/7m56kdhc/

Comment: Thanks @Martin, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you need to use div.

```css
div.left {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
div.right {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/44/9f/02/449f02a1a0328ed5f311112b83407fdf.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right"><span>Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to this code

```css
div.left{
  vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   float:left;
}
div.right{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="left"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/44/9f/02/449f02a1a0328ed5f311112b83407fdf.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="right"><span>Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo </span></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

One good way would be to arrange it in a `table`. I think it's neater and easier to organize.

```css
div.left {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.right {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="left">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/44/9f/02/449f02a1a0328ed5f311112b83407fdf.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="right"><span>Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/qtfj1bo0/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` to section. And  `align-items: center;` if you want to make text center.

```css
section {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="left"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/44/9f/02/449f02a1a0328ed5f311112b83407fdf.jpg" alt="" ></div>
<div class="right"><span>Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo </span></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.left{
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="left"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/44/9f/02/449f02a1a0328ed5f311112b83407fdf.jpg" alt="" ></div>
Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo Demo Demo demo 
</section>
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qtfj1bo0/3/)

just use float left will solve the problem

```
div.left{
   float: left;
}
```